# Is there a mainframe z/OS image to run in cloud platforms?

Tags: zos

I might be asking a stupid question. Is there an OS image for mainframe similar to Linux and Windows? what does it mean GCP or a cloud platform says "can run a custom image of an application" ? Is it only within Linux and Windows flavors ? Please refer any learning links for me to understand the basics.

Example:
https://cloud.google.com/security/shielded-cloud/creating-shielded-images

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer, if it answered your question.

Comment: The only way to legally run a z/OS system on the cloud at the moment is to purchase an Enterprise Edition of the Z Development & Test environment. It needs to be an Enterprise Edition, not a Personal Edition, since the PE works with a physical USB dongle for licencing, whereas the EE uses a licencing server which you could then run in the cloud as well. IBM is working on a cloud-style solution for renting z/OS systems, but it's not yet announced when it'll be launched or at what price.

Answer (score 1):

You need a license from IBM to run z/OS, and you must run it on an IBM approved platform. Approved platforms are IBM Z systems (and predecessors), and IBM zPDT environments.

Hercules is **not** an approved platform, and it is unlawful to run any recent IBM mainframe operating system on Hercules.